# The Dual of $L^{\infty}$ and the Radon-Nikodym Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

I've run into an issue with an exercise and I think that more assumptions are needed in order for the result to be true.  Here is the exercise:

---

Let $\nu:\mathcal{M}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a signed measure and $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be $\sigma$-finite.  Show that there is a function $f\in L^{1}(X,\mu)$ for which $$\int_{X}g\,d\nu=\int_{X}g\cdot f\,d\mu \quad \forall g\in L^{\infty}(X,\mu)$$

---

It is assumed that $X$ is complete with respect to $\mu$ (an assumption that seems irrelevant for this problem). Do we not need to assume that $X$ is finite with respect to $\nu$ and that $\nu \ll \mu$? I ask because it seems that ultimately this boils down to whether or not I can express $\nu$ as $$\nu(E)=\int_{E}f\,d\mu,$$ which by (a corollary to) the Radon-Nikodym Theorem I must have these properties. If this is the case, then I can just use the RNT, the Kantorovitch Representation Theorem, and a previous exercise which says that if $\nu \ll \mu$ and $f\geq0$ is measurable then $$\int_{X}f\,d\nu=\int_{X}f\,\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}d\mu.$$
I figure either this or I am possibly misunderstanding something about the problem statement. Any hints or tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Title is very misleading. Nobody knows what the dual of $L^{\infty}$ is.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The dual of $L^{\infty}(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is $BFA(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$, the space of bounded finitely additive signed measures that are absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right! A proof of this fact can be found in the first (if I remember correctly) volume of 'Linear Operators' of Dunford and Schwartz.

Comment: Regardless, the title is at best misleading, because the problem has noting to  do  with the dual of $L^\infty$.

Comment: This was in the section of the book about the dual of $L^{\infty}$ and as I stated in my question, the Kantorovitch  Representation Theorem is to be used to solve the problem, which is about the dual of $L^{\infty}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Note that 
$$\tag1\int_{X}g\,d\nu=\int_{X}g\cdot f\,d\mu \quad \forall g\in L^{\infty}(X,\mu)$$ implies that $\nu\ll \mu$, so that hypothesis cannot be avoided.

The typical counterexample would be to take $X=\mathbb R$, with $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure, and $\nu=\delta_0$, the Dirac measure. Then you cannot have $(1)$, since 
$$
g(0)=\int_X g\,d\nu
$$
is not even well-defined on $L^\infty(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "... is not even well-defined on $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$".  You mean that if $f,g\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\mu)$ are such that $f=g$ (so $f=g$ almost everywhere) then we may not have $$\int_{R}f = \int_{R} g$$ since 0 might be in the set on which $f$ differs from $g$?

Comment: Yes. It you are talking about $L^\infty$ of a diffuse measure, evaluating at a point is not well-defined.

Comment: Okay, now my question becomes is there any way to show $\nu\ll\mu$ given only the assumptions above, or is that possibly something that is missing from the problem statement? I hesitate to believe the problem would be stated without necessary assumptions.

Comment: No. Like I mentioned, if you are free to choose $\nu$ then you can make it a Dirac measure against Lebesgue measure, and the equality fails.

Comment: Alright, thank you.